# JavaScript - Abrir nova guia e fechar atual

Tags: javascript, html, html5, navegador-de-internet

Como posso abrir uma nova guia em `JavaScript` e fechar a atual?

tentei usar este código mas de erro 500 no servidor

redirect.php

```
echo "</script>window.open(https://google.com, "_blank");</script>";
echo "</script>window.close();</script>";
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Isso não é PHP, é JavaScript.

Comment: Verdade, so foi um engano

Comment: Novas abas devem ser abertas apenas com o click do usuário. Esse tipo de prática de abrir novas abas sem a interação do usuário não é aconselhável e a maioria dos navegadores entendem como pop-ups e bloqueiam.

Comment: E você precisa dar escape ao usar aspas duplas no conteúdo dentro de `echo`: `echo "</script>window.open(\"https://google.com\", \"_blank\");</script>";`

Answer (score 1):

Use aspas simples (`'`) ou caracter de escape (`\`) dentro da string. Segue código:

```
echo "</script>window.open(https://google.com, '_blank');</script>";
echo "</script>window.close();</script>";
```

**OU**

```
echo "</script>window.open(https://google.com, \"_blank\");</script>";
echo "</script>window.close();</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Note que faltam aspas no seu `open` e sua tag de abertura de `script` já começa errada.

```
echo "<script>window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');</script>";
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

Você pode adicionar os dois entre uma única `tag` de `script`

```
echo "<script>window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');window.close();</script>";
```